# Change decorator in java project on the basis of URL

Tags: java

Change decorator in java project on the basis of URL these URL may belongs to TWO or more HOSTS

Comment: please give some more context/explanation/examples. As of now, this question is unclear.

Comment: Please clarify your context. What decorator and what project?

Comment: How big is your office? I know some interior decorators that have good rates and that will make your office look wonderful.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your talking about struts decorator.

In the WEB-INF/decorators.xml file you can define patterns that tell which decorator to use for which url's

A few examples:

```
<decorator name="all" page="decorator.jsp">
    <pattern>/*</pattern>
</decorator>

<decorator name="other" page="decorator2.jsp">
    <pattern>/other/*</pattern>
</decorator>

<decorator name="test" page="test.jsp">
    <pattern>*/test.jsp</pattern>
</decorator>
```